# Make UISearchBar background clear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I am not able to clear search bar I have tried to make it clear by setting its background color clear and I have also placed one image under searchbar

I have also made clear background of searchbar

```
 for (UIView *subview in self.searchBarHome.subviews) {
      if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")]) {
         [subview removeFromSuperview];//please help me to make clear background of uisearchbar
        break; 
    }
}
[self.searchBarHome setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Comment: Did you subclass the search bar?

Comment: @idindu NO i have not I just wanna remove light gray background of uisearchbar

Answer (score 44, accepted):

For iOS7+, all you need to do is:

```
[self.searchBarHome setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.searchBarHome setBarTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]]; //this is what you want
```

***NOTE**: This will not work for iOS6*

---

For iOS6+, the following will take care of it even in iOS7:

```
[self.searchBarHome setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.searchBarHome setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]];
[self.searchBarHome setTranslucent:YES];
```

Comment: thnk u so much for this post... is there any way for iOS6?

Comment: @Vikram : yes, there is a way (_indirect way_)... check updated answer

Comment: thnks to you sir for this solution

Comment: Will u please help me more I will have to use SOAP webservice in my project but I have not tried yet SOAP.... Which classes need to be imported and which methods need to be implemented

Comment: @Vikram : honestly, i haven't used SOAP web services in iOS (_as yet_). try this [link](http://technet.weblineindia.com/mobile/how-to-access-soap-web-services-from-ios-sdk/) (_it seems simple, nothing out of the ordinary_)

Comment: @Vikram : have you done XML Parsing in iOS before? it's difficult to guide you at this point but basically, the flow will be: **1**.Make a SOAP request string **2**.Use `NSURLConnection` to make the request **3**.Get XML as response data **4**.Use `NSXMLParser` to parse the XML and store it in a class object

Comment: @Vikram : try something and when you get stuck then... stackoverflow to the rescue! :) (_let me know if your question doesn't get much attention_)

Comment: Works in iOS9 also. Thanks :D

Comment: I get black background in IOS9

Comment: Thank you! Setting empty UIImage as background did the trick for me

Comment: For people getting a black background, try setting empty UIImage as background. Like mentioned above-[self.searchBarHome setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.searchBarHome setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]];
[self.searchBarHome setTranslucent:YES];

Answer (score 28):

Here's my solution in Swift 3 (a combo of Scarafone's and Andrew2M's answers):

```
for view in searchBar.subviews.last!.subviews {
        if type(of: view) == NSClassFromString("UISearchBarBackground"){
            view.alpha = 0.0
        }
}
```

or alternatively:

```
searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.clear
searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
searchBar.isTranslucent = true
searchBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .any, barMetrics: .default)
```

Comment: Such a cool alternative solution! Tried a lot of things, but only this resolve the problem (iOS 11 Swift 4)

Comment: This is definitely the answer in Xcode 9.3 with Swift 4 (or at least I think it's Swift 4, I'm still getting used to this technology stack).

Comment: `searchBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .any, barMetrics: .default)` is actually enough

Comment: alternate solution doesn't work for uisearchbar in iOS 13

Answer (score 16):

UISearchBar includes two subviews,they are 'UISearchBarBackground' and 'UITextField'. In IOS8, you need to remove 'UISearchBarBackground' to clear it.

```
for (UIView *subview in [[yourSearchBar.subviews lastObject] subviews]) {        
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")]) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: i had to make a combination of this and other answers to get it fully working, but it is a great starting point.

Answer (score 13):

Removing the UISearchBarBackground may result in unknown behavior particularly if as you begin to use the element in more advanced ways.

Ruozi's answer was my preferred solution for grabbing the UISearchBarBackground element however I would suggest setting the alpha to 0 rather than removing the view with the following:

```
for (UIView *subview in [[self.searchBar.subviews lastObject] subviews]) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")]) {
        [subview setAlpha:0.0];
        break;
    }
}
```

Add the above code to your UIViewController subclass that contains an IBOutlet *searchBar. This code snippet will acheive a transparent background for both iOS8 and iOS9.

In addition it may be better design decision to include this code in your UISearchBar subclass in order to avoid cluttering your viewController.

Answer (score 11):

For anyone trying to find a non hacky solution to this, just set the background image to nil on your Storyboard/Xib file. Literally, simply write `nil` in the background image field of the UISearchBar.

Comment: Mind sufficiently blown.

Comment: How is that not hacky?

Comment: Haha fair point @jshapy8 perhaps I should've said `less` hacky?

Comment: actually, this works for any image name you set that doesn't exist. So it's not just nil, you could also write "asdfgh" and it would still make the bar transparent

Answer (score 9):

Simply use `searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal` works for me.

I had used many workarounds for a long time, until i discover this property accidentally, and works like a charm.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to change this...

[image]

To this...

[image]

Use:

```
self.searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = .clear
```

Comment: What I want is the second image, floating over another view, with a clear background. How did you accomplish that?

Comment: This is only available from iOS 13 onwards.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone coming here and not being able to make the remove or alpha solution work for you, make sure you have your searchBar SearchStyle **NOT** on MINIMALIST. Change it to Default and use any of the codes provided here

Answer (score 5):

For iOS 13+ we can simply use:

```
searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = .clear
```

but other solutions like:

```
searchBar.setSearchFieldBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .normal)
searchBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .any, barMetrics: .default)
```

creates a background on the searchBar which hides the placeholder and doesn't allow to interact with the searchBar. The solution for iOS 12 and below is to use  an approach similar to [@Get Schwifty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61032162/7435893).

Answer (score 4):

Setting the backgroundColor and barTintColor did not work me iOS 9+, left me with a black background. However Ruozi solution will work. Here is a swift version of the same code.

```
for view in _searchBar.subviews.last!.subviews {
    if view.isKindOfClass(NSClassFromString("UISearchBarBackground")!) {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Comment: Setting a clear background didn't work for me either. This solution worked though. Here's a suggestion: I pasted your code into an extension for UISearchBar in a function called "removeBackground()". Then whenever I want to clear a searchbar's background i just have to call searchbar.removeBackground()

Answer (score 4):

My solution working on **Swift 4.1 | iOS 11.4** where I change the background and text colors of UISearchBar

[image]

The key is to find the UISearchBar's UITextField component and to change its parameters:

```
let searchTextField = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
searchTextField?.textColor = UIColor.white
searchTextField?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
searchTextField?.attributedPlaceholder =  NSAttributedString(string: "Your Placeholder", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5)])
```

Then I set the "search" and the "clear" image

```
//search image
searchBar.setImage(UIImage(named: "icon_search"), for: UISearchBarIcon.search, state: .normal)
//clear image
searchBar.setImage(UIImage(named: "icon_search_clear"), for: UISearchBarIcon.clear, state: .normal)
```

Comment: Most recent and best answer for Swift 4+!

Answer (score 4):

```
extension UISearchBar {
    func changeSearchBarColor(fieldColor: UIColor, backColor: UIColor, borderColor: UIColor?) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds.size)
        backColor.setFill()
        UIBezierPath(rect: bounds).fill()
        setBackgroundImage(UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!, for: UIBarPosition.any, barMetrics: .default)

        let newBounds = bounds.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: 8)
        fieldColor.setFill()
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: newBounds, cornerRadius: newBounds.height / 2)

        if let borderColor = borderColor {
            borderColor.setStroke()
            path.lineWidth = 1 / UIScreen.main.scale
            path.stroke()
        }

        path.fill()
        setSearchFieldBackgroundImage(UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!, for: UIControlState.normal)

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Subclass the uisearchbar and override initWithFrame and initWithCoder method and set the background color as

```
// For searchbar created programmatically
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self configureSetup];
    }
    return self;
}

// For search bar created on xib
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self configureSetup];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)configureSetup
{
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

and use the subclassed searchbar instead in place where you specified UISearchBar

Answer (score 1):

Oh man! I've been looking everywhere for a solution and trying multiple things. As @gmogames had mentoned above you can use any of these answers, but make sure the Search Bar Style is set to default or it won't work. So, to clarify on the solution this is what worked for me:

Set Search Bar Style to default in the Storyboard or code(wherever you created the UISearchBar.
Then add this code to your view controller:

```
mySearchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = .clear
```

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 12, swift 4.x
A bit too hacky but Debug view hierarchy shows _UISearchBarSearchFieldBackgroundView is responsible to the background color. To get to it, ...

```
for subview in searchBar.subviews.last!.subviews {
   if subview.isKind(of: NSClassFromString("UISearchBarTextField")!) {
       for v in subview.subviews {
          if v.isKind(of: NSClassFromString("_UISearchBarSearchFieldBackgroundView")!) {
                  v.removeFromSuperview()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is all too hacky. I prefer asking designer to accept Apple default color.

Answer (score 0):

```
searchBarStyle = .default
searchTextField.backgroundColor = .yourColor
```

With this combination, you can remove the gray background of searchTextField and set yours!

Answer (score 0):

I tried @Johnson's answer however it didn't work well for me. (**iOS 13, swift 5**)

However the logic behind the solution seemed well. So tried to iterate all subviews of the searchBar and it worked!

I hope, it will help :)

---

Solution also worked for me in **iOS 12.4** - **swift 5**

**Remove Background Method**

```
private func removeBackground(from searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    guard let BackgroundType = NSClassFromString("_UISearchBarSearchFieldBackgroundView") else { return }

    for v in searchBar.allSubViewsOf(type: UIView.self) where v.isKind(of: BackgroundType){
        v.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

**Helper Methods -> UIViewExtension**

```
extension UIView {

    public func allSubViewsOf<T : UIView>(type : T.Type) -> [T]{
        var all = [T]()
        func getSubview(view: UIView) {
            if let wrapped = view as? T, wrapped != self{
                all.append(wrapped)
            }
            guard view.subviews.count>0 else { return }
            view.subviews.forEach{ getSubview(view: $0) }
        }
        getSubview(view: self)
        return all
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5.4, iOS 14.5.

Here is the default `UISearchBar`, on top of a white background:
[image]

And the same setup on top of a grey background:
[image]

To make the background of the search bar clear, set the search bar style to minimal. This removes the search bar's background and makes the search field translucent. 
`searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal`

[image]

[image]

Then, set the search text field's background color to whatever you want. In this case, I've set it to white.
`searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = .white`

You can see the result of this here:
[image]

[image]

If you set `searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = .red`:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

On **iOS 17, Xcode 15,**

If you want to change from

[image: UIsearchbar default ui appearance]

to

[image: Ui SearchBar appearance needed]

I used the following code

```
        self.barSearch.barTintColor = .white
        self.barSearch.isTranslucent = false
        self.barSearch.backgroundColor = .white
        self.barSearch.searchTextField.backgroundColor = .white
        self.barSearch.layer.borderWidth = 2
        self.barSearch.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
```

Along with in Storyboard, **Search Style - Prominent** and **Bar Style - Default**