# How to create Transparent background for UITableView and UISearchBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

In my application i added one `UITableView` and `UISearchBar` and its background by default white color. I would like to change the background of both items to clear or transparent, For that i tried to change the background colors .

```
tableview.tintColor=[UIColor clearColor];
srchbar.tintColor=[UIColor clearColor];
```

But its not affect on UI. How to do it properly?

The UI screenshot given bellow .

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make UISearchBar background clear](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20993092/make-uisearchbar-background-clear)

Answer (score 1):

For TableView

```
[self.yourtableView setBackgroundView:nil];
[self.yourtableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

And asign clear color to cell

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

And for UISearchBar

```
[self.yourSearchBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.yourSearchBarsetBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]];
[self.yourSearchBar setTranslucent:YES];
```

Comment: Hai...thank you.....by using ur code i can change table view but search bar not getting changed.Its background is white itself.....

Comment: This change is global means for all search bars
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

Answer (score 0):

For iOS7+, all you need to do is:

```
[self.searchBarHome setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.searchBarHome setBarTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]]; //this is what you want
```

as written in [Make UISearchBar background clear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20993092/make-uisearchbar-background-clear)

Comment: what do you want to achieve? make everything "red" or just remove the "gray overlay" from the search view?

Comment: I think by making clear background for all controllers automatically it look likes red.