# Customize every single UISearchBar From AppDelegate Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

I have this code below in my `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
func customizeBars() {
        let bartintColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 20/255, green: 160/255, blue: 160/255, alpha: 1)
        UISearchBar.appearance().tintColor = bartintColor
        window!.tintColor = UIColor(red: 10/255, green: 80/255, blue: 80/255, alpha: 1)
}
```

I call this function (`customizeBars()`) in my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        customizeBars()
        return true
}
```

I also have this in the UISearchBArDelegate if it makes a difference:

```
func position(for bar: UIBarPositioning) -> UIBarPosition {
    return UIBarPosition.topAttached
}
```

But for some reason when I run my app it doesn't change the `tintColor` of any of the `UISearchBars` I have in my app or my `window` tint color. Is there something I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to change the color of Textfield text color, cancel button and search icon color only ?

Comment: @Saleh Yeah I want to change these things: Textfield text color, cancel button, search icon color only, and portion surrounding the UISearchBar like the gray part in the picture above in my question. As seen in the picture the only thing that changed was the color of the cursor.

Comment: You should be able to create an extension of UISearchBar that changes the color upon initialization.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the search bar color using this below line of code -

```html
UISearchBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.red    // Change the color here
```

But I saw that, tint color(for cancel button, search icon and text color) is not working in iOS 10, swift 3.
It used to work before in older versions. Let me try if i can find something to change the tint color of search bar.

Comment: I do not see a `barTintColor` property on the `UISearchBar.appearance()`. I only see `tintColor`. Also when I do that I actually noticed that the color does change except it is hidden behind the gray portion that the `UISearchBar` is on. Should I remove the background view of the UISearchBar?

Comment: barTintColor is a property of UISearchbar to change the bar color and same thing is happening for me as well, it's not displaying in the UIsearchbar suggestion box. But you open the UISearchbar class, then you will see that function is available. You can remove the background view of UISearchbar.

Comment: Seems like you have to change the color of rest of the elements using manually for each searchbar. No way to change it for all using appearance() function. This must be a bug from apple.

Comment: Oh ok. Do you know how I can remove the background view of the UISearchBAr? I tried using the solution here offered by Scarafone: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20993092/make-uisearchbar-background-clear but it doesn't work in Swift 3.